# Why does awk print on non-null strings and positive numbers

Tags: awk, portability

I've noticed some `awk` examples which use `1` instead of `print` to print `$0` (eg. [To conserve space, I normally use '1'](http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt). and on this site).

Is this a documented / safe practice, or is is it subject to breaking in some versions; past, present or future?

Here are some examples:

```
echo 'a-does-print-$0' | awk '"x"'    
echo 'b-does-print-$0' | awk '$0'   
echo 'c-does-print-$0' | awk '1'
echo 'd-does-print-$0' | awk '(1-2)'  
echo 'd-does-print-$0' | awk '{$0="abc"}1'  

echo 'nothing-prints' | awk '{$0="abc"}'  
echo 'nothing-prints' | awk '$999' 
echo 'nothing-prints' | awk '(1-1)'  
echo 'nothing-prints' | awk '1-1' 
echo 'nothing-prints' | awk '0' 
echo 'nothing-prints' | awk 'unsetVar' 
echo 'nothing-printw' | awk ''

echo 'crashes' | awk '-3.14159'
echo 'crashes' | awk '-2' 
echo 'crashes' | awk '-1'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So...the format of an `awk` program is a series of `EXPRESSION {
ACTION }` statements.  If you omit the `ACTION` portion, it assumes
`print`, and if you omit the `EXPRESSION`, it matches everything.  So
this prints everything:

```
awk 1
```

Because your expression (`1`) evaluates as "true" (and you have no action).
This is true for all of your "x-does-print" examples, since given
your sample input they all have a non-zero and non-null `EXPRESSION` and no
`ACTION`.  Given an empty input line, `$0` in the second example would not
output anything.

Likewise, your "nothing-prints" examples other than the first one have
an expression that evaluates to "false" (either an empty string or
numeric 0). The `{$0="abc"}` example works differently: it prints
nothing because it doesn't have any printing instruction.  Given a
long input line with at least 999 fields, the second example (`$999`)
would in fact print out the line.

This is fundamental to how `awk` operates. So sure, it's documented,
and it's not going to break.

Note that your "crashes" examples don't actually crash; you've just
made a basic mistake in your shell syntax.  Awk interprets arguments
starting with `-` as command line options.  Quoting them doesn't
change anything.  If you want to pass awk negative numbers like this,
you need to prefix your awk program with `--` to indicate to awk that
it should stop processing options:

```
echo 'crashes' | awk -- -3.14159
```

Will print "crashes", since `-3.14150` is neither an empty string nor
numeric 0.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question of why you would do this with awk, since `awk 1` is really just a longer way of typing `cat`.

Comment: *larks*, you have explained it very well... The simple examples are like `cat`, but a more "realistic" example is more like this: `awk '{$0="abc"}1'` ... I originally thought it must have been a true/false thing, but when the negative numbers failed I figured it was time to ask a question...  I hadn't considered the possibility of `-1` being an arg, but I suppose it's pretty obvious in hindsight :)... Thanks...

Comment: Great explanation, only one correction. The `awk ''` example is more like `awk 'BEGIN {}'` than it is like `awk '0'`.  The first two will not consume stdin; the third will. Try `echo test | { awk ''; echo done; cat; }`

Answer (score 1):

From [the GNU `awk` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Truth-Values-and-Conditions):

> Many programming languages have a special representation for the concepts of “true” and “false.” Such languages usually use the special constants true and false, or perhaps their uppercase equivalents. However, awk is different. It borrows a very simple concept of true and false from C. In awk, any nonzero numeric value or any nonempty string value is true. Any other value (zero or the null string, "") is false.

Yes, that usage is portable and future-safe.

Sidenote, this shows your second example,

```
echo 'b-does-print-$0' | awk '$0'
```

will not print *every* line, only the ones that awk interprets as a true string, i.e. an empty line or a line containing only a way to write the number 0 (`0`, `00`, `0.0e3`, `-.0`, …).